# Finding 2nd and 3rd level connection using Facebook

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a webapp and one of the functionalities is the way how linkedin connections work.
For a given 2 users, we show the path of connections for 3 levels.Is there a way this could be achieved using Facebook API.
I am allowing user to login using facebook credentails and saving the tokens in MongoDB.I used node js for server side processing.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible via the Graph API. You can only get those friends which are also using your app, not all friends (if your app is >=v2.0).